# Finding the maximum in MYSQL but what if maximum value resides in two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the maximum area for each id in the below table:

```
id      name      area
1001    Land AA   0.55
1001    Land AB   0.55
1001    Land AC   0.25
1001    Land AD   0.1
1002    Land BA   1
1002    Land BB   0.8
1002    Land BC   0.4
1003    Land CA   0.65
1003    Land CB   0.22
1003    Land CC   0.22
```

But what if the data contains values that has two or more maximum? For example, 1001 has 2 rows that has its maximum value. When I use this query: **SELECT id, name, max(area) FROM land GROUP BY id**

```
id      name      max(area)
1001    Land AA   0.55
1002    Land BA   1
1003    Land CA   0.65
```

The desired result:

```
id      name      area
1001    Land AA   0.55
1001    Land AB   0.55
1002    Land BA   1
1003    Land CA   0.65
```

Thanks in advance. Please tell me if this question has a duplicate, I can't search for it because I don't know how to explain it in words or what search query to use. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this with a `join` or other condition.  Here is a typical approach:

```
select l.*
from land l join
     (select id, max(area) as maxarea
      from land l
      group by id
     ) lid
     on l.id = lid.id and l.area = lid.maxarea;
```

Another approach which is sometimes more efficient is to use `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from land l
where not exists (select 1 from land l2 where l2.id = l.id and l2.area > l.area);
```

That is, get all rows from `land` where there is no corresponding row with the same `id` and a bigger `area`.

Finally, your query:

```
SELECT id, name, max(area)
FROM land
GROUP BY id;
```

Does not do what you think it does.  `name` doesn't come from the row with a maximum `id`.  It comes from an arbitrary (technically "indeterminate") row for each `id`.  This uses a `group by` extension, which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  In other databases, this would generate a syntax error.  I would advise you to avoid using this extension until you understand what it is really doing.  That is, be sure that all the columns not using aggregation functions in an aggregation query are also in the `group by` (in your query, `name` is not in the `group by`).

Comment: It worked and got a bonus for correcting my query. :)